# App for iOS AND Android in Facebooks app center - do I need to create two apps?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-app-center

I have a mobile app working for iOS and Android, that I want to display in the facebook app center. Much more important: I want to promote the app for both systems via mobile ads. Facebook told me, that I have to create two different apps in the developers center, because for promoting Facebook can't recognize, which system should be promoted. But if I create two apps, two apps will displayed in the app center, isn't it correct? Which means, if I create one app in the developers center with all information to both systems, mobile ads won't work? The app is working with Facebook login on both systems.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It is not Necessary to create a two apps in facebook for Android and iOS you can you use one API ID for both, But you need to provide necessary inputs for individual platforms. "https://developers.facebook.com/"

**For iOS**

Bundle ID:

iPhone App storeID:

iPad App storeID:

**For Android**

keyhashes:

To create keyhashes for android refer http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/